# Asp.Net model binding to wrapped properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am using the ASP.Net MVC 4 and I have a problem about the model binding.

If there are two classes:

```
public class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<JobSkill> JobSkills { get; set; }
}

public class JobSkill {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So I can use Employee as action's parameter, and it's JobSkills property wouldn't be empty if it received data that had nested JobSkills array.

```
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee) {
    var jobSkillAmount = employee.JobSkills.Count();
    ....
}
```

My problem is what if I wrap the JobSkills property to another class, for example:

```
public class HasMany<T> {
    private List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public class HasMany() {
    }

    public class HasMany(List<T> items) {
        Items = items;
    }

    public void SetItems(List<T> items) {
        Items = items;
    }
}

public class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HasMany<JobSkill> JobSkills { get; set; }
}

public class JobSkill {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can't find a way to let action works as before.
Is there any method to let the model binding make it work?

Comment: why you want to wrap it?

Comment: I want to move some logic into the HasMany, so I can do something like that: employee.JobSkills.Save() or employee.JobSkills.Destroy()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the default model binder knows how to bind to `List<T>` but knows nothing about `HasMany<T>.SetItems()` (how could it).

Two options:

1 write your own model binder

or 2 inherit from `List<T>`(untested, maybe it still won't work, but quickest to try out), ie:

```
public class HasMany<T> : List<T> {
    public class HasMany() {
    }

    public class HasMany(List<T> items) {
        this.Clear();
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public void SetItems(List<T> items) {
        this.Clear();
        this.AddRange(items);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change you model like this :

```
public class Employee {
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<JobSkill> JobSkills { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class JobSkill {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and commit HasValue code , you dont need it.